# Save UTF-8 without BOM Visual Studio 2012

Tags: encoding, editing, visual-studio-2012, bom

It seems that Visual Studio 2012 hates UTF-8 without BOM and always adds it, resulting in an empty line in PHP pages.

How can I change the encoding to UTF-8 without BOM (or at least to Unicode...)

Comment: Please add some more info about what you are doing.

Comment: I can not save documents with UTF-8 without BOM encoding using Visual Studio 2012. I have to edit the file in Notepad++ every time to change to that encoding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the free [Fix File Encoding extension](http://www.svprogramming.net/fix-file-encoding/) :

> The free Fix File Encoding extension prevents Visual Studio 2012/2010
>   from adding BOM to UTF-8 files.
>
> Normally, when you edit a UTF-8 file in Visual Studio, it adds the
>   byte order mark (BOM) sequence 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF to the beginning of
>   the file. Sometimes it confuses other applications further processing
>   the file. You can select an encoding manually (File - Advanced Save
>   Options... or File - Save As... - Save with Encoding...), but you need
>   to do it each time you reopen the file:
>
> Fix File Encoding automatically detects when a UTF-8 file is opened in
>   Visual Studio and sets its encoding to UTF-8 without signature. If you
>   don't edit the file, it remains unmodified. If you edit the file, it
>   will be saved without the BOM.
>
> Fix File Encoding lets you configure which files to encode based on
>   the file path and the file extension. By default, only .html files are
>   protected from Visual Studio.

I have no experience with this extension, but it sounds like it answers your needs.